# Facebook iOS SDK integration showing Error in Appdelegate.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

in htttps://developer.facebook.com they have give login with API call Sample, they asked to type following code in my app delegate.m file

```
// Whenever a person opens the app, check for a cached session
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

  // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info"]
                                     allowLoginUI:NO
                                completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                  // Handler for session state changes
                                  // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
                                  // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
                                  [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                }];
```

it is showing me the error like  ---- No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the 'sessionStateChanged:state:error:'
thanks in advance...

Comment: Where you add your code for `'sessionStateChanged:state:error:`?

Comment: Mani i followed this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial  it is the first step but it is showing the error

Comment: Did you see this `Handling session state changes` topic? Did you add this?

Comment: No where we need to add that code?

Comment: You have to add this method. because you already add this call(`self  sessionStateChanged:session.....`) in your block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to above link, You have to add this method in your app delegate.. But you can customize this method according to your view by state(state == FBSessionStateOpen... etc)

```
// This method will handle ALL the session state changes in the app
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{
  // If the session was opened successfully
  // customize your code...
}
```

Comment: mani where it is showing to add the above mentioned code i never saw the code. could you please point me in that document ?

Comment: @PeerMohamedThabib Did you find it? search with this keyword. `Handling session state changes`. You can see the code.